# Applescript: activating remote application failure

Tags: itunes, applescript, remote-desktop

I have an Applescript to quit my local iTunes, access a remote computer and open iTunes there:

```
tell application "iTunes" to quit

set remMachine to "eppc://user@0.1.2.3.4"

tell application "iTunes" of machine remMachine to activate
```

The following error is returned:

> error "iTunes got an error: Application isn’t running." number -600

Yeah, tell me about it. You tell an application to 'open' and it fails because it isn't open.

How can I open an application on a remote machine?

Edit: I have tried changing the script to:

```
tell application "iTunes" to quit
```

set remMachine to "eppc://user@0.1.2.3.4"

tell application "Finder" of machine remMachine to do shell script "open /Applications/iTunes.app"

but the returned error is now:

> error "Finder got an error: Handler does not allow remote events."
>   number -10016

This is actually incorrect as remote events are enabled in System Preferences.

Comment: idk how to fix the issue as written - but I wouldn't think you'd tell Finder to "open..." you'd tell System Events

Comment: Good thought, but returns: error "System Events got an error: Application isn’t running." number -600

Comment: I found a whole page on the subject, idk if it's any use [I can't test here] - http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=19859

Comment: @Tetsujin: looks good. I'll try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tetsujin for [this link](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=19859) which provided the details for the answer.

My script now looks like this:

`tell application "iTunes" to quit
set remMachine to "eppc://user@0.1.2.3.4"
tell application "Finder" of machine remMachine
    open file "Macintosh HD:Applications:iTunes"
end tell`

This does the following:

1. Quits the local instance of iTunes
2. Sets the details of the 'remmachine'
3. Opens iTunes on the remote machine

Comment: Glad you got it :) Don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer, for future Googlers.